# на что в байткоде у дженериков заменяется конструкция <T super MyClass>

Tags: java, generics

Насколько я понял, дженерики после компиляции заменяются в скомпилированном коде на  конструкции без дженериков.

Так, например параметризованный метод

```
      public <T> T f(){
       T t = null;
       return t;
      }
```

Превращается в

```
      public Object f(){
       Object  t = null;
       return t;
      }
```

,код

```
      public <T extends MyClass> T f(){
       T t = null;
       return t;
      }
```

превращается в

```
      public MyClass f(){
       MyClass t = null;
       return t;
      }
```

А во что превратиться

```
      public <T super MyClass> T f(){
       T t = null;
       return t;
      }
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<T super MyClass>` превратится в ошибку компилятора. В отличие от wildcard дженерик не может быть lower bounded.